# How can I delete rows from a Grid View dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am having the grid view in **3*3** I am getting the images into the grid view by urls. In my url i am having n images. I am taking 9 images per page. When the user reaches the bottom I need to delete the above 9 images.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens if the user again scrolls up ?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the row when the user scrolls down might not be a really great idea, as the user might again scroll up and then you would need to redraw the deleted rows once again. Since you have a large number of images to display, maybe you can try to **LazyLoad** the items in your GridView.

The code given [here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) implements LazyLoading for a ListView but I am very sure that you can implement the same thing in GridView also.